# code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0 in if statement

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, dispatch-async

I'm trying to receive data from the network with dispatch_async in Swift. Here is a piece of code which runs new thread:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
    dispatch_async(queue, {
        dispatch_async(queue, {
            self.loadData()
        })
    })
}
```

And here is my loadData():

```
func loadData() {
    var feedItems = [Item]()
    let stringUrl = BASE_URL + "newsfeed.get?filters=photo,wall_photo&count=100&max_photos=10&source_ids=friends,following&v=5.28&access_token=" + accessToken
    let url = NSURL(string: stringUrl)

    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    var response: NSURLResponse?
    var error: NSError?

    println("Loading data")

    let data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(urlRequest, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)

    if data != nil && error == nil  {
        ...
    }
```

But I'm always getting code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0 in the last if statement. If I remove data!= nil, everything seems to be ok but I'm getting the same error in the next if statement while checking another error for nil. What's wrong?

Comment: Why are you doing two nested dispatch_asyncs to the same queue? I'd also suggest using a real networking library like Alamofire.

Comment: `data` is not optional here, and because of that your program crashes. Make `data` optional.

Comment: @Yogesh Suthar data is optional, actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out. It was something wrong with the project. I created a new project and copied source code there. Now it works perfect.